# Session Handling - Flex BlazeDS Java

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

Am facing issue with session timeout. Say for instance, the user logs into the application and he waits for 30 mins (session timeout time) and then tries to get a service through remote object.Ideally speaking, since the session has timeout the user shouldn't be able to hit the remote object, but this is happening the other way round.

web.xml entry :
    
      30
    
Also, after 30 minutes am getting to see the log that seesion is invalidated,

[BlazeDS][DEBUG] FlexSession with id 'NptXY........5559488' for an Http-based client connection has been invalidated.

But still if user tries to invoke the new service, the remote service call is happening. I want it to throw some exception when the session is expired where in I can catch it and show to the user as " Session Expired!!!"

Please let me know if am missing anything. Please its really urgent.

Note: Server: Weblogic 9.1

Also Note that, am not using Spring framework. Its just a basic remoting-config/Services-config calls.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the remote service protected by a check that the user has a valid session where he is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Since, **Flex app** runs on **client side**, and session can be modified other than Flex app like AJAX call from webapp for current user, in either case you have to **check Session Timeout on server**.

Session Timeout can be **calculated** by method provided in API [Interface HttpSession](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

*One way of checking it for Flex app is*

In existing  **remote method** check for Session Timeout and return null or any message to Flex app and show Alert to User that Session is timeOut.

*Other ways are*

1. Make a method to check Session Timeout and call it first.
2. Push message form server on Session Timeout to Flex App.

hopes thats helps